# Makefile сформировать список зависимостей с учётом VPATH

Tags: makefile

Всем привет!
Такая проблема, есть не большой проект на C и Makefile к нему написанный руками. Структура исходников проекта следующая:

```
root
 - src
   - *.c
   - *.h
   - lib
     - aes
       - *.c
       - *.h
     - ble
       - *.c
       - *.h
     - others...
       - *.c
       - *.h
   - drivers
     - radio
       - *.c
       - *.h
     - spi
       - *.c
       - *.h
```

Описал в Makefile переменную VPATH как:

```
VPATH += src
VPATH += src/lib/aes
VPATH += src/lib/ble
VPATH += src/drivers/radio
VPATH += src/drivers/spi
```

В результате сборка объектов идёт правилом

```
$(SRC_C:%.c=%.o): %.o: %.c
    @$(CC) ....-o $(dir $<) $<
```

Но вот список формируется вида "main.o ble.o aes.o spi.o ...o", а хочется чтобы формировался как "src/main.o src/lib/ble/ble.o src/lib/aes/aes.o src/drivers/spi/spi.o"
Это реально? или я многого хочу?

Comment: *список формируется* — список чего? формируется где? p.s. зверский костыль под названием VPATH использовать вряд ли имеет смысл (без достаточно веских причин): его использование очень сильно усложняет понимание содержимого файла и потому весьма затрудняет поиск ошибок.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin список необходимых объектов для сборки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049453/4827341

Comment: а вот было упоминание что VPATH это костыль. Как лучше и изящнее без него обойтись? Описывать список файлов индивидуально с путями?

Comment: файлы с исходными текстами у вас уже структурированы по каталогам. отсюда логически следует и структуризация процесса компиляции.